# Tokenize string based on delimiter in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I need to tokenize string `36-3031.00|36-3021.00` to `36-3031.00` and `36-3021.00` using `|` delimiter.

I have tried like this,

```
PUT text
{
   "test1": {
  "settings": {
    "analysis" : {
            "tokenizer" : {
                "pipe_tokenizer" : {
                    "type" : "pattern",
                    "pattern" : "|"
                }
            },
            "analyzer" : {
                "pipe_analyzer" : {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "pipe_tokenizer"
                }
            }
        }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "mytype": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "pipe_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

But it does't produce exact. Can anyone sort out this use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the correct mapping you should use (including the index name in the REST PUT command). And the `|` character needs to be escaped:

```
DELETE test1
PUT test1
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "pipe_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\|"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "pipe_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "pipe_tokenizer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "mytype": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "pipe_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test1/mytype/1
{"text":"36-3031.00|36-3021.00"}

GET /test1/_analyze
{"field":"text","text":"36-3031.00|36-3021.00"}
```

Comment: GET /test1/_analyze
{
  "field": "productID",
  "text": "36-3031.00|36-3021.00"
} it splits like 36, 3031.00, 36, 3021.00

Comment: Then it means you didn't follow my instructions exactly. I have updated my answer with a complete test.